# draw with dp dimension

Tags: android, paint, pixel

I have a loop af paint that create a circle, all work but on different device I get different paint dimension, I think that is a problem of density, how can I solve the problem?

this is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<360; i = i + 12){
    x = (float) (view.getWidth()/2 + raggio_in * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)));
    y = (float) (view.getHeight()/2 + raggio_in * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)));                 
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tutorial_text));     
    if(i < progress){
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(i, x, y);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF((float) x-deltaX, (float) y-deltaY, (float) x+deltaX, (float) y+deltaY), raggio_elemento, raggio_elemento, paint);
    canvas.restore();
    x = (float) (view.getWidth()/2 + raggio_out * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)));
    y = (float) (view.getHeight()/2 + raggio_out * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)));
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tutorial_text));
    if(i < progress){
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(i, x, y);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF((float) x-deltaX, (float) y-deltaY, (float) x+deltaX, (float) y+deltaY), raggio_elemento, raggio_elemento, paint);
    canvas.restore();   
}
```

Comment: When you draw, you are using **unscaled px**. Scale them accordingly to the dimension, by finding your device scale factor (1.0 on mdpi screens, 1.5 on hdpi screens, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the dimension in `dp` this way:

```
pixels * density + 0.5f
```

`density` can be access calling `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`

`0.5f` is used for rounding